# UIScrollView Indicator Bar

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I was looking at the Apple docs for UIScrollView and saw that the constants for UIScrollView Indicator bars are "default", "black", and "white". I was thinking about using a scrollView without showing the indicator bar on the side of view. I have a very specific case and the bar is making it look awkward and actually seems to be distracting because of it.

If I have a black background and use a black bar I think this would hide it well. Is there a way to turn it off or move it off screen?

Has anyone done this without Apple rejecting it? Or is this a violation of the HIG in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide scrolling indicators if you want - see `showsHorizontalScrollIndicator` and `showsVerticalScrollIndicator` properties in `UIScrollView`. You can set them in IB as well.

Comment: That is great! Thank you! I thought IB would have a property for that. I guess I should have looked there too. I checked the Apple docs, The H.I.G., and StackOverFlow before asking. The answer was in something I use all the time. That figures. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

`UIScrollView` has a couple of properties to disable the scroll indicators. Those are:

[showsVerticalScrollIndicator](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006922-CH3-SW34)

[showsHorizontalScrollIndicator](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006922-CH3-SW33)

Set them to `NO`, either in code or IB, to disable the indicators.